# Running webjob in console works but throws exception on Azure: The remote name could not be resolved: 'xxx.queue.core.windows.net'

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

My webjob deletes documents from my blob storage. If I copy the code to a console app and run it, it runs to completion without error. If I create a new webjob in visual studio (right click my website project and select Add -> New Azure Webjob project), copy the code into the Functions.cs and deploy, Azure throws an exception when running the webjob:

```
===============================================

[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'xxx.queue.core.windows.net' ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'xxx.queue.core.windows.net'
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult)
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result)
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.EndExists(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<CreateCallback>b__0(IAsyncResult ar)
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Listeners.QueueListener.<ExecuteAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.TaskSeriesTimer.<RunAsync>d__d.MoveNext()
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.BackgroundExceptionDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Throw>b__0()
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
[09/09/2016 01:51:44 > fc93a9: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766

=======================================================
```

I don't have a queue so thats probably where the error is coming from but the weird thing is I do not try to access a queue, I am only accessing my blob storage.

Not sure if this helps but my webjobs Program.cs looks like this:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
        config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = TraceLevel.Verbose;

        config.UseTimers();

        var host = new JobHost(config);
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

And this is the only code in the job that uses storage, the rest is database stuff to get lists, etc.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("agentdocuments");

foreach (var doc in expiredDocs)
{
    if (doc.ContentLength == 1)
    {
        // Retrieve reference to blob
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"{doc.SubDomain.ToLower()}/{doc.ClientId}/{doc.FileId}");

        await blockBlob.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I should also add that this only started occurring after updating:

- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs from 1.1.1 to 1.1.2
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core from 1.1.1 to 1.1.2
- WindowsAzure.Storage from 5.0.2 to 7.2.0 and

There were also a few code changes and other updates (like Newtonsoft.Json,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager,Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish) but no code changes with how I accessed the blob.

UPDATE - My webjob ran over the weekend to completion. It failed at 22:23 with the same error as above, but then ran successfully on the retry at 22:24. But then failed again today with the same error. I'm going to try remove the logging as stated by @FleminAdambukulam but strange how it ran without any code changes but then fails again......

Comment: Sounds like some DNS resolution issue. You might want to try isolating by trying to run `nslookup` on your storage account host name from [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console).

Comment: Please check the redundancy level and account type of your storage account. My guess is that either the redundancy type is ZRS/Premium LRS or account type is Blob Storage (instead of regular Storage).

Comment: @GauravMantri Account type is Blob Storage. Why would that cause an issue like this? It was working fine up until a few days ago. The only change were some updates to dependencies. And why does it work outside a webjob?

Comment: `Blob Storage` kind of accounts only support blobs and not queues, tables and files. I am guessing the web jobs infrastructure makes use of queues behind the scenes (@DavidEbbo can elaborate more on that) which your code is not using when ran as a simple application and not as a web job. HTH.

Comment: @DavidEbbo nslookup on the blob works. I tried on the queue which couldn't find anything but that is expected as I don't have a queue. Is GauravMantri correct in that webjobs use queues when trying to access a blob from the job?

Comment: as Gaurav suggests and you mention, the AccountType is Blob Storage. this is a service specific account. Only blob service is available in this account. you can use queues optionally in webjobs.https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-blobs-how-to/

Comment: Right, that sounds like that's the issue. It's the wrong storage account type, so it doesn't support queues, leading to the DNS resolution error.

Comment: @DineshMurthy-MSFT Can you please explain where a queue is being used in my job? I am only accessing blobs in my job unless webjobs use queues under the hood?

Comment: @garethb queues are used internally. I added an answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the storage account is of the special type that only supports Blobs. Even though you are not using queues, the WebJobs SDK relies on them internally. So in order to use the WebJobs SDK, you need to use a regular Storage account.

Comment: FRACKIN FRACK! Excuse my Battlestarian.... But do the Azure gods, who live in the mysterious land above known as 'The Cloud', have some miracle power they can lend me to easily copy my blob to the new storage I'll create that doesn't involve taking my site down to stop new documents being uploaded. I am willing to sacrifice up to 3 goats and one lamb! I know you are just their servant @DavidEbbo but I beg of you, speak to them on my behalf!

Comment: And do you have any idea on why it still works maybe 5% of the time?

Comment: I'm more on the WebJobs side, so not a storage expert. But the tool I've used to copy blobs from one account to another is [azcopy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/). No, I can't explain why this would work at all, sorry!